# Where is "~/.config/gspread_pandas/google secret.json" located?

Tags: python, django, pandas, gspread

I've just started working with Gspread-pandas. And instantly I've bumped into a problem. Documentation and all the tutorials I could find say that I should "*move downloaded JSON to ~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json*".

I know it's supposed to sit right in the home folder but it just doesn't work (
[file path screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKrfw.png)). Any command I run results in:

`Please download json from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and save as ~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json`

Comment: `~` is shorthand for the home directory.

Comment: I was sure it's the home dir as well. But sadly it doesn't work. So that's what frustrates me.

Comment: @GlebIvanov Downvoted because "it doesn't work". Besides, "~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json" is located in `~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json`.

Comment: @GenoChen I have attached a screenshot and specified how it "doesn't work". Please read fully before downvoting.

Comment: @GlebIvanov The picture have NO relation with this question at all. You are showing a project only, with an unrelated path.

Comment: Is `E:\Dev\Projects\DistantRadio` your home directory?  Home directory is not the same thing as the project root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json" is located in `~/.config/gspread_pandas/google_secret.json`.

You must be using Windows, then `~` can be expanded as `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable, for example `C:\Users\<username>`. You are misunderstanding "user home directory" and "project root directory".

Then, they are asking you for putting that file in, for example, `C:\Users\<username>\.config\gspread_pandas\google_secret.json`

Comment: Thank you! I thought it meant project home.

Comment: Problem is, they don't specify if this is project root or user home directory. Just provide the path. That's what got me frustrated.

Comment: @GlebIvanov No, `~` is **always** user home directory. If they are meaning project root directory, then they will explicitly write it.